# Ethernet Frame visualization

Tags: ip, ethernet, networking

One IP packet is fragmented in multiple ethernet frames at sender's side
And at receiver's end, all the frames are combined to get back the IP packet

So is there any way to see what payload each ethernet frame carry separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple packet capture, you can see the frames carrying the fragments. Most capturing and analysis tools explicitly show your fragmented (and possibly reassembled) packets.

Comment: Is it possible using Wireshark?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.